# Derivative of the trace of the power of a PD matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, trace

Suppose $\mathbf{X}$ is a $n\times n$ positive definite matrix, $\mathbf{A}$ is a $n\times n$ constant matrix, and $b$ is a real scalar. The matrix power $\mathbf{X}^b$ is defined to be $\mathbf{U}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^b\mathbf{U}^T$ where $\mathbf{U}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}\mathbf{U}^T$ is the eigen-decomposition of $\mathbf{X}$.

How to compute the derivative of $f(\mathbf{X})=\mathrm{trace}(\mathbf{X}^b\mathbf{A})$ with respect to $\mathbf{X}$? Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks.

-John

Answer (score 2):

First, find the gradient for a simple concrete case, like $b=3$
$$\eqalign{
  f_3 &= {\rm tr}(AX^3) \cr
    &= A^T:XXX \cr\cr
 df_3 &= A^T:d(XXX) \cr
    &= A^T:(dX\,XX+X\,dX\,X+XX\,dX) \cr
    &= A^T:(dX\,XX+X\,dX\,X+XX\,dX) \cr
    &= (A^TX^TX^T+X^TA^TX^T+X^TX^TA^T):dX \cr
    &= (XXA+XAX+AXX)^T:dX \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial X} &= (XXA+XAX+AXX)^T \cr
  &= \Big(\sum_{k=0}^2 \, X^k\,A\,X^{2-k}\Big)^T \cr
}$$
Generalizing the formula to arbitrary values of $b$ yields
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f_b}{\partial X} &=  \Big(\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} \, X^k\,A\,X^{b-1-k}\Big)^T \cr
}$$
In this derivation, I used the Frobenius ( : ) product for algebraic convenience.  You can replace it with the trace if you prefer, since they are completely equivalent $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$

Comment: Thanks. When b is a natural number, you derivative is right. However, when b is a real scalar, such as 1/2 or -1/3, how to get the derivative?

Comment: For any analytic function, appeal to Cayley-Hamilton to write it as a finite-degree polynomial $$P(X)=\sum^{n-1}_{b=0}\,c_bX^b$$So the objective function becomes $$\eqalign{F&={\rm tr}(AP)=A^T:P\cr&=\sum^{n-1}_{b=0}\,c_b A^T:X^b\cr &=\sum^{n-1}_{b=0}\,c_b\,f_b\cr\cr\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}&=\sum^{n-1}_{b=1}\,c_b\frac{\partial f_b}{\partial X}\cr}$$Where the gradient of $f_b$ (for integer $b$) is given by the above answer.

Comment: How to use the Cayley-Hamilton theorem to write it as a finite-degree polynomial? Could you give more details?

Comment: It is known as Lagrange-Sylvester Interpolation.  For example, [here is](http://www.mini.pw.edu.pl/~pkamins/pdf/pme.pdf)  a short paper that explains the technique.